# Changing floating point behavior in Python to Numpy style

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to make Python floating point numbers follow numpy's rules regarding +/- Inf and NaN?  For instance, making `1.0/0.0 = Inf`.

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> ones(1)/0
array([ Inf])
>>> 1.0/0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: float division
```

Numpy's divide function `divide(1.0,0.0)=Inf` however it is not clear if it can be used similar to `from __future__ import division`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at how [Sage](http://sagemath.org/) does it. IIRC they wrap the Python REPL in their own preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do something similar, and I never figured out how to do it nicely. But, I can tell you a few things I tried, that didn't work:

1. Setting float = numpy.float  -- python still uses the old float
2. trying to change float.**div** to a user-defined function  -- "TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type `float`". Also, python doesn't like you mucking with the **dict** object in built-in objects.

I decided to go in and change the actual cpython source code to have it do what I wanted, which is obviously not practical, but it worked.

I think the reason why something like this is not possible is that float/int/list are implemented in C in the background, and their behavior cannot be changed cleanly from inside the language.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap all your floats in `numpy.float64`, which is the numpy float type.

```
a = float64(1.)
a/0 # Inf
```

In fact, you only need to wrap the floats on the left of arithmetic operations, obviously.

Comment: I'm trying to provide numpy like floating point arithmetic in a REPL shell, so explicit wrapping isn't an option.